# NextJS Dynamic favicon and title

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, seo

Greetins, I'm trying to build a webconstructor. Right now my application works like that:

1. I check the url the user is on (for example localhost:3000)
2. I get his project name on my webconstructor (localhost:3000 -> projectName: project1)
3. I fetch the user's website data (for example favicon and title) (project1: {favicon: 'url', ...}
   Is it possible to render the favicon and title before the user enters the page so that it shows the right favicon and title in the browser. Right now I can only get it via useEffect in the main App component (but it's not good for seo). I have tried with getInitialProps but it doesn't seemd to do the job.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible to render dynamic favicon and title. Using the `Head` component from `next/head`. You can also create a `GenericHead` component that you can use whenever you want. Something like:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

const GenericHead: FC<{ title?: string; favicon?: string }> = (props) => {
  const { title, favicon } = props
  return (
    <Head>
      {title ? <title>{title}</title> : <title>Document</title>}
      <meta
        name='description'
        content='your description'
      />
      <link rel='icon' href={favicon ? favicon : '/favicon.ico'} />
    </Head>
  )
}
```

You can add more things to this GenericHead, like OpenGraph meta tags. And use it whenever you want

Comment: Yes, but I doubt it will be prerendered. Right now I will try doing so with _document.js file, yet I will still need to check if it works after hosting my website. Anyways, thanks for your comment